# Removing an integer from a list during iteration?

Tags: python

Here is the code that I'm getting an error on. I'm getting the error: "list index out of range", I know that it's because you can't remove items in an iteration, but I need to and I don't know how.

I'm essentially trying to sort this list but finding the minimum and then appending it to the new list and removing it from the old list, but I don't know how. Please help.

**Code:**

```
list = [22,1,-5,-10,62,-11,36,8]
m = list.index(min(list))
sorted_list = []

for x in range(len(list)):
    if list[x] > list[m]:
        sorted_list.append(list[m])
        list.remove(list[m])


print (sorted_list)
```

Comment: What is this supposed to *do*? It doesn't seem to be sorting anything. Why don't you store the value, rather than its index? What should the outputs be?

Comment: honestly, this could be totally wrong, I'm just trying to get some help :/

Comment: Then explain *what you're trying to achieve*. Given that input, what should the output be? Why?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the list (just use `sorted_list = sorted(list)`), or are you trying to learn how to implement a particular sorting algorithm?

Comment: (Specifically, you appear  to be trying to implement [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).)

Answer (score 1):

This code should take sort the list smallest to largest and then remove the smallest and transfer it to a new list.

```
List = [22,1,-5,-10,62,-11,36,8]
List2 = []
swapped = True
while swapped:
    swapped = False
    for i in range(len(List)-1):
        if List[i] > List[i + 1]:
            List[i],List[i+1] = List[i + 1],List[i]
            swapped = True
List2.append(List[0])
List.remove(List[0])

print(List)
print(List2)
```

Comment: This is a different algorithm than what the OP is trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

For the task you are describing, you would have to find the new minimum every time:

```
my_list = [22, 1, -5, -10, 62, -11, 36, 8]
new_list = []

while my_list:
    my_min = min(my_list)
    new_list.append(my_min)
    my_list.remove(my_min)
```

Comment: im trying to refrain from using the "sorted" option. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @JosephCranney so you want to sort the list without including the smallest element?

Comment: I want to just sort the list by appending the minimum of the first list to a new list, then once that is appended, I want to delete it from the first list, and then repeat... etc. (find the new min, repeat).

Comment: thanks a lot, is there anyway this works with a for loop? just wondeirng, thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

A while loop is better, you need step by step keep the smallest item in the new list (the sorted list), and remove it from the old list, and repeat this until the old list would become empty.

```
   while (len(list) <= 1):
        sorted_list = sorted_list.append(min(list))
        list = list.remove(min(list))

    print(sorted_list)
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.